# How to find the threadID of a Azure Pull Request?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to post a comment on a PR using the Azure API in Powershell.

I've found this resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20thread%20comments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

And I've implemented it:

```
$postURL = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repositoryId/pullRequests/$pullRequestId/threads/$threadId/comments?api-version=5.0"
$prComment = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $postURL -Headers @{Authorization = $pat} -Body $body
```

When I run this with `$threadId = 1` I get:

> Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The requested>  pull request comment thread '1' cannot be found.

When I run it with `$threadId = 0` I get:

> Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The value 0 is outside of the allowed range

This is a image of the comment section of the pull request with id 1:

[image]

So what is the `thread id` of a PR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out by using the API:

`https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repositoryId/pullRequests/$pullRequestId/threads?api-version=5.0`

You can get a list of threads for that PR. Each line in the comment section represents a thread. And where I thought that thread id is linked to the PR (ie. `created by PB` is thread id 1 inside that PR), it is not. Each new thread increments the thread id. So if I add a thread in a different PR it could have thread id `231`. If I add another thread in a different PR it will have id `232`. Which is quite annoying. I can't understand why Azure would implement it this way.

Comment: obviously because they are stored in a separate table and have unique id which gets incremented with each thread.

Comment: How is that obvious? Can you provide any documentation?

Comment: its obvious from implementation you described